# Absolute positioned tooltip (emoji picker) in a GAS dialog?

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, position, tooltip

I have a dialog in my GAS script, and I'd like to add emoji picker to it.
This is my picker of choice: https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-picker-element#usage
All goes well until the moment of actual rendering of the picker. At which time I realize that absolute positioned element still remains strictly inside of a dialog window. So, as it goes now, my only choice is to have a really big dialog.
Or is it? Is there any way to make the element render outside of a GAS dialog window?

I've tried to fiddle with z-index, position etc. The tooltip remains inside of a dialog no matter what.

Below is the code that will allow to reproduce the problem.

**Debug.js**

```js
function emojiTest() {

  const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms/EmojiTest');

  var htmlOutput = html.evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(250);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Test Emoji'); 

}
```

**forms/EmojiTest.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-picker-element@^1/index.js"></script>

  <style>

    /* emoji */
    .tooltip:not(.shown) {
      display: none;
    }

    .tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      top: -30px;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="nameChangeForm" onsubmit="">
    <input type="text" name="cat" required id="nameField">

    <button onclick="event.preventDefault();"></button>
    <div class="tooltip" role="tooltip">
      <emoji-picker></emoji-picker>
    </div> 

    <div id="buttons">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"  >
    </div>
  </form>

  <script type="module">
    import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-picker-element@^1/index.js'
  import insertText from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/insert-text-at-cursor@0.3.0/index.js'

  document.querySelector('emoji-picker').addEventListener('emoji-click', e => {
    insertText(document.querySelector('input'), e.detail.unicode)
  })
  </script>

  <script type="module">
    import * as Popper from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@^2/dist/esm/index.js'
  const button = document.querySelector('button')
  const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip')
  Popper.createPopper(button, tooltip)

  document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
    tooltip.classList.toggle('shown')
  }
  </script> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `At which time I realize that absolute positioned element still remains strictly inside of a dialog window.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script for correctly replicating your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike, you have nothing to apologize for! It's probably my bad English that caused misunderstanding in the first place. I'll add the code to the original question now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot still understand your question. I guessed that `At which time I realize that absolute positioned element still remains strictly inside of a dialog window.` might be the issue that you want to resolve. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand it. So, can I ask you about the details of your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike No problem. Have you tried the code I've provided? If you did, you probably saw that when you click on an emoji button, the tooltip appears underneath the borders of a dialog window. I'd like to be able to see the emoji tooltip in full. https://i.imgur.com/nLI2Fq8.png

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and reply, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

And,

```
<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip">
  <emoji-picker></emoji-picker>
</div>
```

#### To:

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto !important;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: none !important;
  width: 230px;
  height: 210px;
}

.emoji-picker {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And,

```
<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip">
  <emoji-picker class="emoji-picker"></emoji-picker>
</div>
```

When this modification is reflected in your showing script, it becomes as follows.

[image]

If you don't want to use `width` and `height`, please remove them.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike, thanks, it does solve the clipping problem. However, the emoji tooltip is still dependent on the size of a dialog window, and is still fully within its borders. What I was hoping to achieve is a tooltip that overlaps the dialog window and therefore does not depend on its size. Thanks.

Comment: @Basil Vlasyuk Thank you for replying. From `it does solve the clipping problem.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your another issue of `the emoji tooltip is still dependent on the size of a dialog window, and is still fully within its borders. What I was hoping to achieve is a tooltip that overlaps the dialog window and therefore does not depend on its size.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your another issue. And, I cannot find the size from your question and reply. Can I ask you about the details of your another issue?

Comment: What is `What I was hoping to achieve is a tooltip that overlaps the dialog window and therefore does not depend on its size.`? For example, when you remove `.emoji-picker { width: 100%; height: 100%;}` and modify `.tooltip` to `.tooltip { position: absolute; top: auto !important; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; transform: none !important; }` by removing `width: 230px; height: 210px;`, is that your expected result? I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back. I'd like to know if it's possible for emoji tooltip to be out of dialog's borders. Not sure how to rephrase it further so I'll try an illustration. https://imgur.com/a/uXvZVwL

Comment: @Basil Vlasyuk Thank you for replying. I understand your 2nd request. I think that unfortunately, in the current stage, your goal cannot be achieved because of the current specification of the dialog on Google Spreadsheet. I deeply apologize for this. From this situation, I could resolve your question. But, unfortunately, I cannot resolve your 2nd question. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: No worries @Tanaike :) Thank you for trying.

Comment: Thanks again for your recommendations @Tanaike. I'm gonna go ahead and accept your answer, since it seems like the closest thing possible to what I needed. I ended up using it.

Comment: @Basil Vlasyuk Thank you for your response.